# "Passen wie die Faust aufs Auge" bedeutet "total" oder "gar nicht zusammenpassen"?

Tags: meaning, idiom

In [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/passen_wie_die_Faust_aufs_Auge) stehen die zwei höchstwidersprüchlichen Bedeutungen:

> Bedeutungen:
>   [1] umgangssprachlich: ganz und gar nicht zusammenpassen
>   [2] umgangssprachlich: wunderbar zusammenpassen

- Könnte jemand Hinweise geben, um den Ausdruck richtig zu verstehen?

Ich meine, hört man

> **Ne//Natürlich**, das passt wie die Faust aufs Auge"

dann weiß man Bescheid, dass sein(e) Gesprächspartner(in) die erste//zweite Bedeutung meint. Aber ohne das erste Wort, gibt es ein Kriterion, um das zu erfahren?

Comment: Das steht auch im Wiktionary: 'Herkunft:
Die ursprüngliche Bedeutung[1] „nicht passen“ wurde häufig ironisch verwendet, woraus sich die Bedeutung[2] „gut passen“ dann entwickelt hat.[1]'

Comment: @abti  Da steht aber kein Kriterion. Nur, dass beide Versionen existieren, und das die Eine aus der Anderen kommt.

Comment: Wikipedia-Einträge sind sowieso eine problematische Referenz. Sicher gibt es bessere Quellen, die man verwenden könnte?

Comment: Weniger doppeldeutig ist die Redewendung ***Das passt wie der Faust aufs Gretchen.***

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Womit wieder der Unterschied zwischen doppeldeutig und zweideutig belegt ist. Da passt dein Beispiel wie Arsch auf Eimer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laut [diesem Artikel](https://www.swr.de/wissen/1000-antworten/kultur/1000-Antworten-Ist-die-Redewendung-Das-passt-wie-die-Faust-aufs-Auge-positiv-oder-negativ-zu-verstehen,1000-antworten-2210.html), den mir das Google-Orakel ausgespuckt hat, ist die Redewendung in ähnlicher Form und mit verneinenden Bedeutung 1 seit dem 15. Jh belegt.

Eine Nutzung mit ironischem Unterton und damit entgegengesetzter Bedeutung 2 lässt sich seit dem 17. Jh belegen.

Ich würde sagen, es hängt davon ab, um wessen Faust und Auge es sich handelt ;)

Comment: Die Ironie steckt doch schon in 1 drin: Die Formulierung klingt ja erstmal danach, als ob etwas gut passen soll. Ironischerweise wird dann aber ein Vergleich gewählt, bei dem es überhaupt nicht passt. Bedeutung 2 wird dann wohl verwendet, wenn die Ironie nicht verstanden wurde.

Answer (score 6):

Eigentlich passt die Faust ja nicht aufs Auge - zumindest möchten wir sie da nicht haben. Dafür spricht Bedeutung [1]. Faust und Auge passen nicht zusammen.

Verwendet wird es doch aber eigentlich immer so: Bedeutung [1] + Ironie = Bedeutung [2]

Ergo: Wir meinen immer, dass es wunderbar zusammenpasst. Da braucht man kein "erstes Wort".

Comment: Mir ist es ausschließlich in der "passt gut"-Form bekannt. Ebenso wie "Arsch auf Eimer".

Comment: "Eigentlich passt die Faust ja nicht aufs Auge" - rein geometrisch ja schon irgendwie; der Bereich zwischen Augenbrauen und Wangenknochen ist von Größe und konkaver Rundung her näherungsweise das genaye Gegenstück zur entsprechend großen, konvexen Faust. Genau deshalb verwirrt mich persönlich diese Redewendung jedes Mal.

Comment: Ich kenne das auch nur in der "passt gut"-Bedeutung. Bevor ich vor ein paar Monaten erstmalig auf diese Frage gestoßen bin, wäre ich nichtmal für einen Sekundenbruchteil auf die Idee gekommen, dass man diese Redewendung im Sinne von "passt nicht" verstehen könnte.

Answer (score 2):

Für mich passt die Faust NICHT aufs Auge - 
so habe ich diesen Spruch auch viele Jahre lang gekannt, leider wird er neuerdings immer öfter in umgekehrter Bedeutung verwendet (was mich sehr stört, da ich es einfach als falsch empfinde)

Comment: Ja ja, _neuerdings_, also genauer gesagt seit dem 17. Jahrhundert. Wie alt sind Sie doch gleich?

Comment: Aber im 15. Jahrhundert war es noch anders. Die Älteren werden sich erinnern.

Answer (score 1):

Wer schon mal eine Faust aufs Auge bekommen hat, weiss danach, dass "die Faust wirklich nicht aufs Auge" passt, sie hinterlässt nämlich eine Geschwulst und ein sogenanntes "Veilchen" - ein "blaues" Auge, welches noch für längere Zeit daran erinnert, dass man eine Faust aufs Auge bekommen hat. Also bitte: Was soll daran positiv sein? Wieso will man immer häufiger damit ausdrücken, dass etwas besonders gut passt?

Comment: Vielleicht sieht man die Sache ja aus der Lage desjenigen, dem die Faust gehört?